# Lightning Web Components - Not available in app builder

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

I'm developing a lightning web component with org based development and I'm finding that the component isn't available in the app builder, despite (as far as I can tell) making it available in the component definition. I've attempted this with a my own component and also directly copying the "HelloWorld" Lightning component in this trailhead:

[Create a Hello World Lightning Web Component](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component)

My component is pretty simple, and I'd like it to be available on the Contact record page. Here is the config on that component:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="contact_CRSProfileLayout">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Use this component to display the fields from this person's related CRS Profile</description>
    <masterLabel>CRS Profile</masterLabel>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>  
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Contact</object>
            </objects> 
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I've deployed the components into my sandbox from Visual Studio Code using the "SFDX: Deploy Source to Org" command and I can see that the lighting web components are in the sandbox when I navigate to them in the admin interface (I can't confirm that they exactly match what I'm seeing in Source, but I can see the timestamp of their update is correct).

[image: Successful deployment]

However, neither of them are appearing in the ap builder. I would expect both to appear on a record page app builder and the hellowWorld component only to appear on a home page Lightning Page.

[image]

Are there general troubleshooting steps I should be taking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue wasn't the deploy, it was me - I'm inexperienced with Visual Studio Code.

I wasn't following the correct order of actions. The local save wasn't happening, so I was repeatedly deploying a "blank" component to the server.

I've ensured that the local save is happening and the components are now showing up as expected.

Answer (score 33):

You currently have the `isExposed` attribute set to `false`, it needs to be set to `true` for the component to be available on the targeted pages and app builder.

```
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
```

By [definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags):

> `isExposed`
>
> A Boolean value. Exposes the component in all orgs, and in Lightning App Builder and Community Builder

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd already tried that (and the helloWorld component was set to Exposed = true. Unfortunately, this hasn't made any difference. I've made the change in the original question so it's clearer.

Comment: Did you redeploy the configuration file after making the change?

Comment: Thank you for checking, but yes - I'm clicking "SFDX: deploy Source to Org" after every change, just to see.

Comment: You have few different components mentioned in your question and that your original question was updated. I will recommend to start with one of the components say hello world and try to update the attribute and see if that works. There’s no other attribute which makes the component available in app builder.

Comment: Additionally just to make sure that the deployment was successful, check for message `ended with exit code 0` to make sure the deployment was indeed successful.

Comment: Jayant - both components have "i<isExposed>true</isExposed>" and I'm seeing "ended with exit code 0" when deploying. I will add this to the question so that others can see

Comment: And do you see the component bundle’s last modified updated in the Org?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91510/discussion-between-bigears-and-jayant-das).

Comment: This worked for me, after adding the `targets` element described in [Muzaffar's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/268879/3709). Both actions were necessary to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 16):

Add targets in .js-meta.xml file of the component.

```
<targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
</targets>
```

Comment: He already has "lightning__RecordPage" as a target in there. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This is a good answer - fixed it for me.

Comment: This also worked for me, after toggling `isExposed` in [Jayant's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/255161/3709). Both actions were necessary to resolve my issue.

Comment: Same, this works with isExposed=true

Answer (score 1):

Go to componentname.meta.xml file under lwc in VS
Check true attribute set to true.

If *isExposed* is false, the component is not exposed to Lightning App Builder or Community Builder.
To allow the component to be used in Lightning App Builder or Community Builder, set  *isExposed* to true and define at least one , which is a type of Lightning page.

Comment: Please provide a reference for material that's copied from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) so that others can benefit from the context. This answer is really the same as that already posted by Jayant Das, but we have lots of unsolved questions that could benefit from your knowledge of LWC.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in a Trailhead Playground when I had the setting `"salesforcedx-vscode-core.experimental.deployRetrieve"` set to `true` in vscode. Whenever I deployed it would say the component updated. After I turned it off and deployed, it said it was Added (new), and was then visible.

I've used this feature in other orgs plenty of times so I don't know if this issue is specific to Trailhead Playgrounds