# I can push an LWC component, but I cannot see or use an LWC component in the default org?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Once deployed, I can see the component from the Home page in Custom Code > Lightning Components > Lightning Components, however when I Edit the Sales Page (or any other) it is not under Custom components to be dragged onto the page?!

I have spent hours on this, reading articles like these below, and trying all their suggested options, but have been unable to find a solution to this *fundamental* problem?

Same issue (seems common), however no help:

[https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000QvQUQA0](http://https:/developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000QvQUQA0)

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000E6hFQAS

[Lightning Web Components - Not available in app builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255160/lightning-web-components-not-available-in-app-builder)

Any help would be appreciated?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show meta file? and also in which object/record home page?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>`

i created a scratch org and tried to use the sales object/app/record.a

Comment: How about moving the apiVersion to 46.0?

Comment: Yup tried that too!?

Comment: Can you share the full code (including the .html file?) the screen shot of the push just shows a js file

Comment: The full code is here: https://github.com/rikster/u-lwcsessions

(it's just an OTB blank sdfx project, w/ a helloworld lwc component)

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are exposing to the type of page (app,record and object home), You should also mention which objects in specific contexts in `targetConfigs`.

For example, below is sample code which exposes to record page in Account and Opportunity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="poc">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>LWC Comp POC</masterLabel>
  <description>This is a demo component.</description>
  <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
  <targetConfigs>
      <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
          <objects>
              <object>Account</object>
              <object>Opportunity</object>
          </objects>
      </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: I used the above and changed fqn="helloworld", ie. the same the component. Created a new Opportunity, edited it, and **there is still no custom component** to drag onto the page?

Comment: check if it got deployed properly. Then refresh the components list, it will definitely come

Comment: You can see here that it was pushed and uploaded successfully, but is still not avail under custom? [Salesforce Component Issue](https://photos.app.goo.gl/P4RysD8LEC8TCFwQ9)

Comment: I cant open link. Can you paste the photo in question. You just need to edit the question and paste the photo where required

Comment: ok, done. The link should work?